# Why is my table cell width wrong in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout, width, html-table

I've got a table with two rows. The first row just has three cells. The second row has two cells, with the first cell containing another table that needs to fill the whole cell.

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="WIDTH: 205px;">1</td> <!--This width doesn't apply in Chrome-->
        <td style="width:100%;">2</td>
        <td style="WIDTH: 5px;">3</td>
    </tr>                

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

                <TABLE width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;table-layout: fixed;">
                    <TR>
                        <TD style="width:130px;">
                            A</TD>
                        <TD style="width:90px;">
                            B</TD>
                        <TD style="width:230px;">
                           C</TD>
                    </TR>

                </TABLE>        
        </td>
        <td>
            D
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Simple enough, really....or so I thought.

It appears as I would expect in IE. But Chrome seems to not apply the width of the first cell correctly. It seems to be affected by the table in the cell below.

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I get around this?

Comment: Try setting the width of `<td style="width:100%;">2</td>` to `auto` instead of `100%`

Comment: Out of interest, why are you trying to build the table in that way? What kind of layout are you aiming for? What data will it hold?

Comment: @Blowski I'm using tables for page layout. Don't hate me- I just couldn't figure out how to do it with divs.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Two things you should do:

- On the table element, use `table-layout: fixed;`
- Insert columns and give them a width

  - (You could also assign width to table headers/cells of the first row)

Like this:

```
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 205px;">
        <col style="width: auto;">
          <!-- Use "width: auto;" to apply the remaining (unused) space -->
        <col style="width: 5px">
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr> 

    <!-- Etc. -->
```

Comment: Style "table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;" on the table element does all the magic! Thanks a lot!!