# Table column change behavior depending on content (colspan)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with colspan that doesn't behave nice.

Please compare the following fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucaswiener/WBdc8/

http://jsfiddle.net/lucaswiener/WBdc8/1/

I expected the second fiddle to behave just like the first one.

If they appear the same to you, with my browser (latest chrome) the first one render the first column (the one that contains "foo") without any padding. The second one have a lot of left padding in the first column.

First fiddle html code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        foo
    </td>
    <td class="lol">
        bar
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">foo walked into a bar. When he ordered food, the bar kicked him out :(
    </td>
</tr>
```

Second fiddle html code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        foo
    </td>
    <td class="lol">
        bar
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">foowalkedintoabar.Whenheorderedfood,thebarkickedhimout:(
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can this be?

EDIT:
Just tested this in Firefox, which seems to work as expected. I guess the problem applies to webkit browsers.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have given .lol a width of 100% - there are 2 columns so it can't be 100%.  Give it a valid width and your table will work properly no matter the contents of the colspan row

Comment: Okay, I thought that was a valid way of making a column in a table to use as much width as possible. What approach would you instead suggest  to make the right column use all remaining space? Would it be more valid if i set the first width to 1% and the second to 99%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the width of both columns in the first row.  If you just specify the single width then it will try to get to that width, but since your second jFiddle has a second row with no spaces in the test, it can only do 50% whereas the first comes out to about 90% (since you specified 100%).

Best bet is to specify the width of both td's:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="first">
            foo
        </td>
        <td class="lol">
            bar
        </td>
    </tr>
    .....
```

and add/change css:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

.lol {
    width: 90%;
}

.first {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes that indeed fixed the layout. But I still do not really understand why. Could you please elaborate "but since your second jFiddle has a second row with no spaces in the test, it can only do 50%"? :)

Comment: Honestly I don't know for sure, but it appears that the browser tried to follow your 100% TD width as best it can.  In your first case it tries to "push" your bar text all the way to the left but runs into "foo" so that's as far as it goes. In your second case it does the same but since the second row has longer text with no spaces, so it tries to calculate the longest text length and makes sure it leaves at least that much room. Since your second row has no spaces the best it can do in a 2 column is 50%.

Comment: Okay, yes that makes sense. I'm now leaning towards setting the first column width to 1% and then the second one to 99%. Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I guess it depends what you are really trying to do and the type of data you are dealing with - but certainly specifying the two would be best and then seeing if your data looks right.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of Chrome is a little different respect Firefox and IE in this case.
Try to add in your style `table-layout: fixed;`, e.g.:

```css
table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

And adjust the colum width (less than 100%). It should fix your problem.

See also:

[Why is my table cell width wrong in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212608/why-is-my-table-cell-width-wrong-in-chrome)

---

If you want to make a column use all remaining space you can use `*`:

```css
.lol {
    width: *;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The problem is that I cannot set a width of the first column, since I do not know how wide it's gonna be. I want the first column to be as wide as it needs, and then the second column to be as wide as possible. That's why I only specified width 100% of the second one. How would I achieve this differently?

Comment: "\*" is exactly what you need: you can have the first column as wide as it needs (depending from the content), and the second column (using in the style "width:\*;")adapts to the remaining width.

Comment: Perhaps is more clear for you thinking as 100% /relative/ to the full table width and not to the content of the cell.

Comment: Okay. Since the content of the first column changes during runtime, I dont feel comfortable specifying a fixed width for the column and then using table-layout: fixed;. I think I'm gonna go with first column 1% and then second column 99%, or would that be stupid on some way?

Comment: You can avoid to use table-layout:fixed (it was just to explain the difference of preview in Chrome). You can left unspecified the first column width, and use \* for the second column: <tr><td>First column</td><td style='width:\*;'>Second column</td></tr>

Comment: Did you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/lucaswiener/WBdc8/9/ It's not like I showed in the first fiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle you have ".lol {width: 100%;}", you should instead use ".lol {width: \*;}". I agree with @Arthur Frankel: the final style of your table depends only from your intentions: you can use 1% for the first column, but in this case the content of the first cell would be splitted when filled by some words separed by space, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. Does this seem right? http://jsfiddle.net/lucaswiener/WBdc8/12/
It still doesn't behave like the first fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing wrong with your code. If you change the text in the second row of your code, it will automatically changes to the 1st fiddles.

Try it and let me know if this helped you!

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm missing something, but that is my point. How can the last row (that is colspan 2) affect the widths of the first ones? If this isn't what you mean, please update your answer with example code :) To be clear: I want to achieve the layout of the first fiddle with the content of the second fiddle.