# Generated HTML tables that I've successfully changed several indirectly... except this particular one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My site has these interactive tables that are inert until activated by an instructor when they are testing students. The backend is controlled by a vendor and I am the lowly web developer who cleans up their mess on the frontend so things look presentable. I've managed to change several tables indirectly through CSS and JS, but I can't apply anything to the HTML directly to the table since it's generated when the page loads. This particular table is perplexing,it will not shrink down to 720px. I tried everything from `adddClass`, `nth-child`, fixed sizes, etc. My last attempt was to write a function that set attributes to td's. It worked and it'll show on the developer tools but the actual table didn't shrink at all. I've been up 24+ hours so I might just be tired and not aware of simple mistakes. Anyways here's my [demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/A4aRNCHAIwwy7Y6rYtc9/). Thank you very much any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this: [Why is my table cell width wrong in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212608/why-is-my-table-cell-width-wrong-in-chrome)
Tables have a property called `table-layout` which is by default set to `auto`. It allows the table to be flexible and gives it the ability to distribute column widths on the fly. Setting my rogue table this way:

```
table-layout: fixed; width: 100%
```

made it behave and honor the widths I had assigned to it. Here's more details on [table-layout](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/)

[**Demo**](http://embed.plnkr.co/jSL4Q4f2writSYIuMhoM/)

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that this only happens in Chrome, but in Firefox and to a certain extent IE (it's a little off, but that's what you'd expect from a half-baked piece of work), are ok.