# Firefox table cell width completly different than Chrome's

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-tables

I have a problem with my table cell width. On Chrome it works perfectly, but on Firefox it looks a lot different and I don't whats causing it.

This is the chrome one, looking perfect:
[image]

This is the Firefox one, being squeezed tight:
[image]

Any idea why this is? Heres my code.

```css
/* Latest games */
.lp-latestgames {
    height: 466px;
}
.lp-latestgames .title {
    margin-left: 460px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
.lp-latestgames .table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead th {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    color: white;
    height: 49px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th { border-bottom: none; }
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td {
    height: 81px;
    border-top: 2px solid #111316;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr:first-child > td { border-top: none; }
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:first-child,
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:first-child{
    /* ÜBERARBEITEN!!!!! */
    padding-left: 460px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:last-child,
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:last-child{
    /* ÜBERARBEITEN!!!!! */
    padding-right: 460px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td > .gd-c-versus {
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #494949;
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:nth-child(4),
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:nth-child(5),
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4),
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lp-latestgames">
        <!-- Games -->
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png"></th>
                <th>Price Pool <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png"></th>
                <th>Entry <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png"></th>
                <th>Avg Skill <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png"></th>
                <th>Time Remaining <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_up.png"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Im bored. Fite me<span class="gd-c-versus">1 vs 1</span></td>
                <td><img src="img/gd_content_coin.png"> 20</td>
                <td><img src="img/gd_content_coin.png"> 10</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="730" class="circle"></td>
                <td>00:00:32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EG vs LGD - Wild Cards Entry<span class="gd-c-versus">5 vs 5</span></td>
                <td><img src="img/gd_content_coin.png"> 1.500.000</td>
                <td><img src="img/gd_content_coin.png"> 20</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="980" class="circle"></td>
                <td>00:01:47</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cyka blyat<span class="gd-c-versus">5 vs 5</span></td>
                <td><img src="img/gd_content_coin.png"> 20</td>
                <td><img src="img/gd_content_coin.png"> 10</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="730" class="circle"></td>
                <td>00:02:4</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: See my answer, I had the same problem a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

`.table { table-layout: fixed }`

See snippet
See [**POST**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360778/2813224)

```css
/* Latest games */

.lp-latestgames {
  height: 466px;
}
.lp-latestgames .title {
  margin-left: 460px;
  margin-top: 56px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}
.lp-latestgames .table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;    /*<<<=====  ADD THIS RULE RIGHT HERE */ 
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead th {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  color: white;
  height: 49px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td {
  height: 81px;
  border-top: 2px solid #111316;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr:first-child > td {
  border-top: none;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:first-child,
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:first-child {
  /* ÜBERARBEITEN!!!!! */
  padding-left: 460px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:last-child,
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:last-child {
  /* ÜBERARBEITEN!!!!! */
  padding-right: 460px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td > .gd-c-versus {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #494949;
}
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:nth-child(4),
.lp-latestgames .table thead > tr > th:nth-child(5),
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4),
.lp-latestgames .table tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lp-latestgames">
  <!-- Games -->
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name
          <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png">
        </th>
        <th>Price Pool
          <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png">
        </th>
        <th>Entry
          <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png">
        </th>
        <th>Avg Skill
          <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_dn.png">
        </th>
        <th>Time Remaining
          <img src="img/gd_content_arrow_up.png">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Im bored. Fite me<span class="gd-c-versus">1 vs 1</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="img/gd_content_coin.png">20</td>
        <td>
          <img src="img/gd_content_coin.png">10</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="730" class="circle">
        </td>
        <td>00:00:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EG vs LGD - Wild Cards Entry<span class="gd-c-versus">5 vs 5</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="img/gd_content_coin.png">1.500.000</td>
        <td>
          <img src="img/gd_content_coin.png">20</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="980" class="circle">
        </td>
        <td>00:01:47</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cyka blyat<span class="gd-c-versus">5 vs 5</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="img/gd_content_coin.png">20</td>
        <td>
          <img src="img/gd_content_coin.png">10</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="730" class="circle">
        </td>
        <td>00:02:4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work, it now looks like this: [link](http://puu.sh/lr7Fl/e59600a191.png) on both chrome and FF

Comment: Isn't that the objective? To have Chrome behave like Firefox or vice versa? If you can get the same look on both browsers then count your blessings. Even if it's not the look desired, you can go on and work on Chrome and have some confidence that Firefox will not stray again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared `<!DOCTYPE>`  in your html page, if not give it a try. This doctype is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

Comment: well, I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my first line

Answer (score 0):

Try to set th or td width using rem instead of px
Each rem equals 16px